# Spring Config Client - ConfigClientWatch

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I am looking at the class ConfigClientWatch in the package package org.springframework.cloud.config.client;

I was expecting that I could use this to poll the server periodically to see if the config had changed and then execute an refresh.

I am not able to get this to work? How does the value

String newState = this.environment.getProperty("config.client.state");

Get updated.

I have not been able to find any documentation on this.

Thanks in Advance

Raghu

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this property is only used by Vault backend. Anyway, there is a thread in the Spring Config's GitHub proposing changes to support other backends such as Git.

If you are using Git-backed configurations, this solution may work for you:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1378#issuecomment-492073851

Please, upvote the GitHub thread so this feature gets accepted.